# Pandas load jsonl to dataframe with complex inner structure

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a super complex data format and I want to load it to a dataframe. This is how my jsonl file looks like:

```json
{'elem1': [['this is the first element', {'inner_elem': [[[1, 2, 'first'], [3, 4, 'second'], [5, 5, 'third']]]}]]}
```

This is what I have tried:

```py
with open(f"{path}/data.jsonl", encoding="utf8") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

df_inter = pd.DataFrame(lines)
df_inter.columns = ['json_element']

df_inter['json_element'].apply(json.loads)

##### ERROR here
df_final = pd.json_normalize(df_inter['json_element'].apply(json.loads))
```

So the first part works fine. It load the data into a data frame.
However, in the normalization the data is normalized into a diagonal df with `elem1` with the col name for each line.
What I'd like to have is the `elem1` as a column value of col. `name`, the text ("this is..." in its own column
and the text of the `inner_elem` e.g. `first` in a column with the name `inner_elem1`, for the second text column value: `inner_elem2`, and so on. I know I have to somehow unpack the values. Problem ist just that I do not really have the `keys`so I am clueless how to access the values inside. So I have no clue how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your expected output? It looks like your df only has one column and the type of the column is dictionary, this kinda defeats the point of pandas and if that is your intent, just use a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

- start with `json_normalize()`
- expand top level list with `explode()`
- expand dict with `apply(pd.Series)`
- a few more `explode()`

You have a dataframe with no embedded lists or dicts

```
js = {'elem1': [['this is the first element', {'inner_elem': [[[1, 2, 'first'], [3, 4, 'second'], [5, 5, 'third']]]}]]} 

# pd.json_normalize(js["elem1"])
df = pd.DataFrame(js).explode("elem1").reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(df["elem1"].apply(pd.Series)).drop(columns=[0]).explode("inner_elem").explode("inner_elem").reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.explode("inner_elem")
```

|  | elem1 | inner_elem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | this is the first element | nan |
| 1 | {'inner_elem': [[[1, 2, 'first'], [3, 4, 'second'], [5, 5, 'third']]]} | 1 |
| 1 | {'inner_elem': [[[1, 2, 'first'], [3, 4, 'second'], [5, 5, 'third']]]} | 2 |
| 1 | {'inner_elem': [[[1, 2, 'first'], [3, 4, 'second'], [5, 5, 'third']]]} | first |
| 2 | {'inner_elem': [[[1, 2, 'first'], [3, 4, 'second'], [5, 5, 'third']]]} | 3 |
| 2 | {'inner_elem': [[[1, 2, 'first'], [3, 4, 'second'], [5, 5, 'third']]]} | 4 |
| 2 | {'inner_elem': [[[1, 2, 'first'], [3, 4, 'second'], [5, 5, 'third']]]} | second |
| 3 | {'inner_elem': [[[1, 2, 'first'], [3, 4, 'second'], [5, 5, 'third']]]} | 5 |
| 3 | {'inner_elem': [[[1, 2, 'first'], [3, 4, 'second'], [5, 5, 'third']]]} | 5 |
| 3 | {'inner_elem': [[[1, 2, 'first'], [3, 4, 'second'], [5, 5, 'third']]]} | third |